# Reading all variables and other details in .mjs (module type javascript file) using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

I am wondering, how can I read variables names, classes names, and other stuff in .mjs file using Node.js.

I have for example file:

```js
class AppRequestResult {
    constructor() {
        this.test = new TestRequests();
        this.subject = new SubjectRequests();
        this.question = new QuestionRequests();
    }
}

function abc() { return 2; }
function def() { return abc(); } 

const text = "sometext";

export const AppRequest = new AppRequestResult();
export const ApiUrl = `localhost/app`;
```

And how to retrieve:

**Variables:**

- text
- AppRequest (mark it as exported in result)
- ApiUrl (mark it as exported in result)

**Classes:**

- AppRequestResult

**Functions:**

- abc
- def (mark it as exported in result)

I tried to search for packages in Node.js that could do that, but I found none.
Also I tried to use "import()" function in Node.js but it only displays exported things.
My target is to combine all .mjs source files to one file and to do that I have to find a way to rename certain variables that are in the .mjs files and rename it to prevent "Already defined" error.